# How do I use a new ipython kernel in Atom?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor, hydrogen

I created a data_science kernel for `ipython` by using the following commands:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name data_science --display-name "Python (Data Science)"
```

This creates a kernel with all my conda/pip data science packages. I can create a notebook with the new kernel, but what I would really like is to add this kernel to the Hydrogen Package in my ATOM text editor.

How do I add this kernel to my Hydrogen ATOM package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on windows you just need to reboot ATOM and it will automatically detected the new kernel.

Comment: Hej, you have removed the question, but just in case, see https://ideone.com/zesSMm

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't do any additional to run Hydrogen with a new kernel.

- Just press ctrl/cmd + shift + p to open command pallette,
- then type in `hydrogen select`,
- choose `Hydrogen: Select Kernel`

Hydrogen automatically will update kernel list and show you a message about it. Further you should see list and pick up from it necessary kernel. If you don't find the kernel it maybe be because there isn't a `language` field in the `kernel.json`. It should look like:

```
{
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "language": "python"
}
```

You can find `kernel.json` checking data-paths that listed by command `$ jupyter --paths`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above did not work for me.  I had to run `Hydrogen: Update Kernels` within atom in order for Hydrogen to see newly installed kernels.  This is briefly mentioned in the [atom website](http://atom-packages.directory/package/hydrogen/) under the heading "Kernels".

Answer (score 0):

```
PyK: was my env name, which I get to with 

    $ source activate Pky

And within this I used the command

    (Pky)/path/name/ $python -m ipykernel install --user --name Pyk --display-name "Pky3"

This worked. Otherwise it would put in 
/miniconda3/envs/Pky/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json 
which is useless for Atom
ls -l  ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 oon oon 4096 Nov  2 19:55 julia-0.6
drwxrwxr-x 2 oon oon 4096 Nov  2 20:14 Pyk *
That's where it needs to be.
in 
    $jupyter --paths
    config:
        /home/hyoon/.jupyter
        /opt/miniconda3/envs/SPk/etc/jupyter
        /usr/local/etc/jupyter
        /etc/jupyter
    data:
        /home/hyoon/.local/share/jupyter
        /opt/miniconda3/envs/SPk/share/jupyter
        /usr/local/share/jupyter
        /usr/share/jupyter
    runtime:
        /run/user/1000/jupyter
```

Check all the dir in *data:

Answer (score 0):

run:

> source activate thisenv
>
> python -m ipykernel install --user --name thisenv

and then restart atom

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions are not up to date or not enough.

follow and run it: https://nteract.io/kernels
and after that restart Atom or type [Win10] `Ctrl` + `Shift` +`P` and `update kernel`, choose the option `Hydrogen: Update kernels`